# How can I always read the date in VBA excel macro as mm/dd/yyyy?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am facing a problem in reading date values from an excel column. All the cells in excel column contains date in format mm/dd/yyyy. I want to extract date and month field from the date for some work, for this I am reading the date and extracting values from it using `Format(dateValue, "mm.dd")`. this is creating some issue in dates when the date is less than 12 (thus when it can be confused with month field).

It is reading 1/31/2022 correctly, but when it encounters something like 11/8/2022, it interchanges the date and month fields. How can I solve this issue?

P.S. I already searched for this issue before posting this, thus don't want suggestions like change the default date format in my system. I can't do it because I have to use this macro in multiple systems where the system date format differs.

I think setting date format while reading a date is a common functionality which should be available, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: If the value is `11-31-2022` and the format is `mm/dd/yyyy` then my best guess is that Excel sees it as text since the format and value is not the same.

Comment: Just to be sure, how exactly did you want Excel to format `11-31-2022`? In most countries that date does not exist.

Comment: I want the Excel to format 11-31-2022 as 31st November 2022, which as I said in my post it reads correctly and gives me 31st as the date and November as the month. The issue is when it reads the date 11-8-2022, it should give me 8th of November, but instead gives me 11th of August.

Comment: So here is a calendar of 2022. The calendar that most agree with. Where is 31st of November? I can't find it. https://www.pashacoffee.com/calendars/2022-calendar-with-holidays-printable-free-vertical-green/

Comment: Okay, yeah sorry. It was 31st of January, while writing this question I changed the dates for external reasons and just wanted to show that the issue is occurring in dates where the day is smaller than 12. Didn't realized that the date doesn't exists. Thanks for pointing it out. Still my problem persists, can you give solution for that?

Comment: There is too much inconsistency in your question that it's hard to answer. As pointed out before, is it `/` delimited or `-` delimited? Your last edit shows that months are written in `01` format where as days are written as `8` only (no leading zero).

Comment: Okay, again it is my fault as I modified dates in my question but yes the date is delimited by `/` not `-` and there is no leading zeroes in either month or the date. Also, yes when I read the date like this `date = ws.Cells(row_num, col_num).value` it returns me an object of date type. I don't know if it is because I declared my variable is decalred as Date, but I think if the excel can't detect the date in the cell then it would throw error, I don't know much about Macros and this is my first time working in VBA so I can't be sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the string length is not static due to non leading zeros then we need to split the dates to an array and build it to a date with DateSerial.

```
Sub dates()

    Set Rng = Range("A1:A2")
    For Each c In Rng
        arr = Split(c.Text, "/")
        'c.Value = DateSerial(arr(2), arr(0), arr(1)) ' uncomment if you want to replace the dates in the cell
        Debug.Print DateSerial(arr(2), arr(0), arr(1))
    Next
    
End Sub
```

After this code has run the cells should contain a proper date which can be manipulated using the cell format options.

Answer (score -1):

This can be fixed by parsing the date as text and manually interpreting each section.

```
Sub Test_Date_recognition()
'loop through a range, in this case A1:A5, and recognise mm/dd/yyyy dates
Dim rngDates As Range, Cell As Range
Set rngDates = Range("A1:A5")

Dim datevalue As Date

For Each Cell In rngDates
    If Not Cell.Text = "" Then
        datevalue = DateSerial(CInt(Right(Cell.Text, 4)), CInt(Left(Cell.Text, 2)), CInt(Mid(Cell.Text, 4, 2)))
        
        'Output
        Debug.Print Format(datevalue, "mm.dd")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Almost nailed it.. `11-31` becomes `12.01`. `11-8` becomes `10.23`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb7ef.png

Comment: Then `Dim D As Integer, M As Integer, Y As Integer`, parse them separately before putting together in the `DateSerial` function, and see which is parsing incorrectly.